# How can I redirect unauthorized users to a login page based upon the area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, redirect, asp.net-mvc-areas

I've got an ASP.NET MVC5 website that will be divided into public and administrative sections.

There is optional authentication on the public side, with some views restricted to only authenticated users with the appropriate role.  If users attempt to access public controllers without being authorized, or not having the appropriate role, I want them to be redirected to the "public" sign-in page.

This is working as desired with just a simple attribute:

`[Authorize(Roles = "Organizer")]`

However, if users attempt to access any content in the Admin area, if they are not authenticated, or are authenticated but do not have a role of "Administrator", then I want them to be redirected to a different login screen.
 (https://localhost:44300/Admin/Account/Login instead of https://localhost:44300/Account/Login).

Is there an easy way to apply an alternate login redirect for the entire area?

Comment: You can write your own custom authorize attribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a custom authorize attribute, so inside `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` you can redirect unauthorized users to specific login page based on area's name:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            var areaName = filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
            if (areaName.Equals("Admin"))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                    RouteValueDictionary(new {controller = "Account", action = "Login", area = "Admin"}));
            }
            else if(areaName.Equals("Public"))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                    RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" }));
            }
           // other conditions...

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, we used this code to get current area name:

```
var areaName = filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
```

Comment: if you happen to be using aspnet rc2 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization there is not virtual functions you can overrrrrrrride swory

Comment: So what do you do then in the case of AspNetCore @JeremyConterio?

Comment: @Saca they got rid of it.  Check out this link, he explains why and the work around
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/03/15/get-started-with-asp-net-core-authorization-part-1-of-2/

Comment: Where in project to add the class?